# Get first link in div using beautifulsoup Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, hyperlink, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get this link using beautifulsoup from this HTML:

```
    <div id="downloads" style="text-align:left">
        Download as Excel tables:  
<a href="crispor.py?batchId=Kn3CuFPN9QbwruIqkBGk&download=guides&format=xls">Guides</a>

    <a href="crispor.py?batchId=Kn3CuFPN9QbwruIqkBGk&satMut=1">Saturating mutagenesis assistant</a><br>
            <small>Tab-sep format:  
    <a href="crispor.py?batchId=Kn3CuFPN9QbwruIqkBGk&download=guides&format=tsv">Guides</a>
```

I've tried this code:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True, text='Guides'):
             crisporDL = link['href']
```

but this is outputting the second link above as you can see both have the text 'Guides', how do I get the first link? as the first link return an XLS file whereas the second a TSV file, I need the xls file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use id selector with `a` tag selector passed to `select_one`. `select_one` returns the first match. It should be faster than using find.

```
soup.select_one("#downloads a")['href']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the *[find()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)* method, which returns only the first match.

```
crisporDL=soup.find('a', href=True, text='Guides')['href']
```

In this case you don't need to use a for loop.

One other possibility without making much change to you code is to add the [limit argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-limit-argument) to your *find_all()*.

```
soup.find_all('a', href=True, text='Guides',limit=1)
```

Although it would be totally unnecessary here, there can be cases in which you may want to get the *first n matches*.